# Cloudwatch alarm that specifies which value of a dimension fired it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

This may be a little hard to explain, but I will try:

We'd like to have an alarm on a metric which has a dimension, but have the alarm identify which value of the dimension it's firing on. I don't know if this is possible.

As a for example, say we have the CPUUtilization metric, the dimension is instance ID, and we have 3 values in this dimension: i-1, i-2, i-3. (I'm contriving this, I'm not specifically thinking of real cloudwatch metrics).

What I'd like to be able to do is define an alarm that says "if CPU utilization for any one value in the dimension goes over 50%, fire an alarm and tell me the dimension's value". E.g. if i-2 goes over 50%, the alarm would tell me that it was i-2 that exceeded the threshold.

Am I asking for way too much?

(The underlying challenge is that I'd rather not have to change alarms as resources are added and removed; I'd be happy with the alarm firing just to tell me one of the items has exceeded the threshold, but ideally our ops staff would like the alarm to tell them exactly which dimension value has exceeded it, without having to look elsewhere.)

Thanks!